# Warning Augmented Dickey Fuller test

Tags: r, time-series, p-value, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am testing stationarity in data and I got warning in the Dickey-Fuller test about p-values which is following: p-value smaller than printed p-value. First I plot the data in the graph:

[image]

Then I applied Dickey-Fuller test and the result is following:

```
    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  yield_to_maturity
Dickey-Fuller = -8.6694, Lag order = 8, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Warning message:
In adf.test(yield_to_maturity) :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
```

Is there anything wrong with my data or should I ignore this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong. You are simply notified that the actual p-value is smaller than 0.01. Think of it as rounding up from whatever the actual value is to 0.01. And clearly, your time series does not have a unit root. This is visible from the graph.

Comment: oh, okay thank you